# What is the model number for product MP2F2LL/A

Tags: ipad

I'd like to purchase a case at the same time as purchasing this iPad from Apple's website, but I can't seem to figure out what the actual model number is.  I can't find any reference to iPad's with A9/M9 processors.  First image is from their store page, second image is the relevant 'technical specifications' from the link at the bottom of the first image.

Thanks!

[image: iPad MP2F2LL/A]

[image: Technical specifications]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPad (5th generation)

Year: 2017
Capacity: 32, 128 GB

Model number (on the back cover): 
A1822 on the iPad (5th generation) Wi-Fi

A1823 on the iPad (5th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is the model that is coming out 3/24.  Nothing on the business purchasing site indicated this.  Sorry about the confusion.